# Whate are some locations to post job requests for iPhone developers online?

Tags: iphone

I am looking for an iPhone developer for a consulting job. The job is a single project and will have a well defined set of requirements. The problem is I don't know where to go to post for something like this. The developer would of course have a contract and get paid.

What are some sites i can post a job description to for iPhone developers?

Comment: Depends on the quality of developer you want. You can surely find some on oDesk or other similar sites, but I'm not so sure you want the penny developer who abandones your project mid-stream because the commonwealth games are in town :p

Comment: I'm looking for a professional, quality, developer and they would be compensated appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

37Signals has an iPhone specific job board category.

http://jobs.37signals.com/categories/6/jobs

I also see lots of iPhone developer jobs posted over at ArsTechnica:

http://jobs.arstechnica.com/

I think an interesting way to hire an iPhone dev would be to sponsor DaringFireball.net. You would probably get a lot of decent iPhone developers at least seeing the ad.